# Alter check constraint on Postgres domain

Tags: postgresql

Given an existing Postgres `DOMAIN` with `CHECK` constraint:

```sql
CREATE DOMAIN code as CHAR(1) 
CHECK (value IN ('A', 'B', 'C'));
```

I need to alter the `CHECK` constraint to add `D` as a member to the valid set `A`, `B` and `C`.

Since the new constraint is a superset of the first it seemed acceptable to first `DROP` the existing constraint and then `ADD` it again; i.e:

```sql
ALTER DOMAIN code 
DROP CONSTRAINT code_check; -- constraint is implicitly named `code_check`

ALTER DOMAIN code 
ADD CONSTRAINT code_check 
CHECK (value IN ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')); -- new constraint
```

Are there possible issues with this approach, or is there a better method?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Theoretically, it is possible that a concurrent session will insert a row that violates the constraint at the moment the domain has no constraint. Reversing the order of commands will prevent this possibility. Since the new constraint is a superset of the old one you can suppress checking values in existing columns using the domain:

```
ALTER DOMAIN code 
ADD CONSTRAINT code_check_new 
CHECK (value IN ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')) NOT VALID;

ALTER DOMAIN code 
DROP CONSTRAINT code_check;

-- if for some reason the constraint name is important:
ALTER DOMAIN code 
RENAME CONSTRAINT code_check_new TO code_check;
```

Per [the documentation:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-alterdomain.html)

> Newly inserted or updated rows are always checked against all constraints, even those marked NOT VALID.

Comment: Excellent point and suggestions, thanks! And in my case the table is very large so presumably adding `NOT VALID` will speed up the operation greatly.